# Removing items from one observable array is affecting another observable array

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

```
 vm.patientList(datacontext.patientNames());
 var patientsForClient = vm.patientList.remove(function (patient) { return patient.ClientId == vm.newCase().ClientId() });
 vm.patientList(patientsForClient);
```

patientList and patientNames are two observable arrays. When I am removing items from patientList, I see that the same items are removed from patientNames as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to both arrays are pointed to the same underlying array. Instead of passing a reference you need to clone array and then do what you need with the cloned one.

```
vm.patientList(datacontext.patientNames.slice(0));
```